# angular universal host sitegroud

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have Created a new angular project and converted it to universal. After running  `npm run build:ssr` i got file structure like this

```
dist
   ----my-project
      ---browser
      ---server
```

and when i run command `npm run serve:ssr` my server is running on port localhost:4000 but now i want to host my project on my siteground hosting server where i uplaod my dist folder file (browser and server) using filezila, but i got an error 404 then i upload package.json file and connect through ssh to my terminal and install first node after that i put command npm install on derectory where i have upload all file with package.json but again i am fail. please if any one have idea to help me.

Comment: What's the web server on siteground? You need to configure it for universal

Comment: I have a hosting plan on sitegroud so i want to host angulr project in angular universal